# Call a function according to variable value

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I have the following code

```
class MyToggle
  constructor: (component) ->
    ...
    @tagName = 'i' || 'button'
    ...

    toggleItems: =>
     MAGIC HAPPENS HERE

    updateI =>
      ...

    updateButton =>
      ...
```

`tagName` is either `i` or `button` and in `toggleItems` I'd like to call the update function according to `tagName`.

When `tagName` is `i` I want to call `updateI`
When `tagName` is `button` I want to call `updateButton`

Any ideas how I could do so?

thanks

Comment: In JS, `var method = 'updateButton'; this[method]();` (except with conditional logic to set the value of `method`). Not sure of the CoffeeScript syntax.

Comment: Thanks `@[@tagName]()` is basically what I was looking for.